# Trigger SqlBrite to update from Stetho debug bridge

Tags: android, sql, sqlbrite, stetho

I'm using SqlBrite for reactive database updates, and Stetho for debugging. From stetho, I can insert a new row into the database from the SQL console. Is there any way I can get this row I've manually inserted to trigger SqlBrite to update my UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting a row directly into your database file, so you are not interacting with `DatabaseOpenHelper` or `JDBC`, so I don't see any way to trigger `DatabaseOpenHelper` that you have inserted new row.

please add some of your code snippet or snapshot to get the idea